# No parameterless constructor defined for this object nopCommerce 4.0

Tags: c#, constructor, asp.net-core-2.0, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.0

When I'm trying to add a view for edit data reason, it gives me the error `No parameterless constructor defined for this object`

This is my controller:

```
public class MyNewPageController : Controller
{
    MyNewPageController c = new MyNewPageController();

    public MyNewPageController()
    {

    }

    public IActionResult Index(PedroJorge.DAL.ProductDAL pd)
    {
        List<CS_mostrarModel> pList = new List<CS_mostrarModel>(pd.Read());

        return View("~/Views/MyNewPage/Index.cshtml", pList);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
    {
        List<CS_mostrarModel> pList = new List<CS_mostrarModel>();
        //Get the student from studentList sample collection for demo purpose.
        //You can get the student from the database in the real application
        var std = pList.Where(s => s.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(std);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product std)
    {
        //write code to update student 

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
```

---

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }


    public SampleContext(DbContextOptions<SampleContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().ToTable("Order");
    }

}
```

Model:

```
 public class CS_mostrarModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int PersonsNumber { get; set; }

    public string TourType { get; set; }
    public int CarsNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong and I already tried everything that I saw in internet, so if someone know how to fix this please help!

Comment: when/where do you see this error? at compile time or run time?

Comment: Why is the controller creating an instance of itself in a local field? Smells like a stack overflow to me.

Comment: Whatever you have developed is in a wrong way, I would highly recommend you to see the implementation of other plugin or default code of nopCommerce and learn *what is dependency injection is*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless that is a typo, then chances are that having the controller creating an instance of itself in a local field is causing a stack overflow exception when the framework is trying to activate the controller.

Each instance will try to create another instance until you run out of space on the stack.

In previous versions, the exception thrown when creating a controller was swallowed by the framework and the standard unhelpful

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

message was thrown.

Remove

```
 MyNewPageController c = new MyNewPageController();
```

from the controller and it should be able to be initialized when requested.

Comment: I already fixed the error but know when I create the Razor Page for Edit reasons in runtime when I click on the button edit it sends me the error CS0103: The name 'PageContext' does not exist in the current context'
do you know how to fix this ?